# Nixos how to configure custom desktop session?

Tags: nixos, xmonad

After setting up a new Nixos installation, upon logging into the `lightdm` greeter I got an error of `Failed to start session`.

I've installed a custom `xmonad` executable, and I'm NOT using the default one.

I could get it to work by adding the following to my config:

```
displayManager.defaultSession = "none+xmonad";
windowManager.xmonad = {   
  enable = true;
};
```

What is this "session" configuration exactly? And how do I configure my own rather than hackily using the default xmonad one?

---

I tried setting the default session on it's own with just the following:

```
displayManager.defaultSession = "none+xmonad";
```

But got an error of:

```
trace: Default graphical session, 'none+xmonad', not found.
Valid names for 'services.xserver.displayManager.defaultSession' are:
  

error: The option value `services.xserver.displayManager.defaultSession' in `/etc/nixos/services-pineapple.nix' is not of type `session name'.
(use '--show-trace' to show detailed location information)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve it with the following:

```
    displayManager.defaultSession = "myxmonad";
    displayManager.session = [
      {
        manage = "desktop";
        name = "myxmonad";
        start = ''exec $HOME/.xsession'';
      }
    ];
```

Found the answer here: https://discourse.nixos.org/t/opening-i3-from-home-manager-automatically/4849/2